# Identifying pinescript swing high and swing low points

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

my problem is i draw lines from wicks while determining swing high and low points in pinescript language. But I want to draw a line from the opening and closing price at the same time. How can I do it. The codes I use are as follows.Thanks.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Svup.jpg)

```
study(title="Para Basma", shorttitle="Para Basma", overlay=true)

// Inputs
pvtLenL= input(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Uzunluğu Sol Taraf")
pvtLenR= input(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Uzunluğu Sağ Taraf")

// Yüksek ve Düşük Pivot Noktaları Alın
pvthi_ = pivothigh(high, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
pvtlo_ = pivotlow(low, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)

// Çizdirmeden önce Zorla Pivot tamamlama.
Shunt = 1 //Pivotu yazdırmadan önce kapanmayı bekle? 1 gerçek için 0 yanlış için
maxLvlLen = 0 //Maksimum Uzatma Uzunluğu
pvthi = pvthi_[Shunt]
pvtlo = pvtlo_[Shunt]

// Mevcut Pivot Seviyesi için kaç mum olduğunu sayın, Yeni sıfırlama durumunda.
counthi = barssince(not na(pvthi))
countlo = barssince(not na(pvtlo))

pvthis = fixnan(pvthi)
pvtlos = fixnan(pvtlo)

hipc = change(pvthis) != 0 ? na : color.maroon
lopc = change(pvtlos) != 0 ? na : color.green

// Display Pivot lines
plot((maxLvlLen == 0 or counthi< maxLvlLen) ? pvthis : na, color=hipc, transp=0, linewidth=1,     offset=-pvtLenR-Shunt, title="Top Levels")
plot((maxLvlLen == 0 or countlo < maxLvlLen) ? pvtlos : na, color=lopc, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR-Shunt, title="Bottom Levels")
```